# Check if streets are the same or not in array

Tags: arrays, c, file

From file I uploaded streets with code of taxi.
Every taxi has several street where he starts from.

E.g. Brad Pitt 12345

E.g. Brad Pitt 33333

E.g. Brad Pitt 34567

My task is to show all unique addresses these 3 examples are only **1** street.

My code:

(function) `driver(taxi,drives, i, &counter);`

```
void driver(Taxi *taxi, char *drives, int i, int *counter)
{
    int yesNo=0;
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(strstr(taxi[j].drives, taxi[i].drives)==NULL)
            yesNo=1;
    }
    if(yesNo==0)
        ++*counter;

}
```

Streets are the same but numbers at the end are different. My question is, how to store only unique addresses.

Comment: Try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: There is no question in your post. You need to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will always set `yesNo` to 1 because you don't skip the element `i` in the loop, try:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{
    if(j != i && strstr(taxi[j].drives, taxi[i].drives)==NULL)
        yesNo=1;
}
```

Also notice that your approach will fail on cases like "Brad Pitt & Angelina Jolie 33333", `strtol` can help to fix that, an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *streets[] = {
        "Brad Pitt 12345",
        "Burt Reynolds 1234",
        "Brad Pitt & Angelina Jolie 33333",
        "Angelina Jolie & Brad Pitt 33333",
        "Brad Pitt 3456789"
    };
    int n = sizeof streets / sizeof *streets;
    const char *street = "Brad Pitt";
    size_t len = strlen(street);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strncmp(streets[i], street, len) == 0)
        {
            char *ptr = NULL;

            strtol(streets[i] + len, &ptr, 10);
            if (*ptr == '\0')
            {
                puts(streets[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Brad Pitt 12345
Brad Pitt 3456789
```